# Помогите найти ошибку в определении модели Django

Tags: python

```
class Post(object):                                  # 1
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)             # 2
content = models.TextField()                         # 3
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)     # 4
def __unicode__(self):                               # 5
    return self.title()                              # 6
def get_absolute_url(self):                          # 7
    return '/question/%d/' % self.pk                 # 8
class Meta:                                          # 9
    db_table = 'qa__question'                        # 10
    ordering = ['-creation_date']                    # 11
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думаю что это 3, 5, 10 строка, но это не верный ответ(

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1274867/edit))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильные ответы:

[image: Ответ]

1. Наследование происходит не от объекта Model
2. Метод self.title является константой и должен возвращаться без скобок в конце
3. Имя не должно содержать нескольких подчеркиваний, потому что Django использует нотацию подчеркиваний для внутренних нужд (например фильтрация)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!